# How to fill NAs with previous n rows' mean or median?

Tags: python-3.x, fillna

I have a time series data set where on some rows NAs show up. I would like to fill those NAs based on previous n days' (rows) mean or median. To do this, I have created new columns with rolling mean. However, I am looking for a method without creating a new column (with apply function?).

Here is my way:

```
ens['vol_5mean'] = ens['vol'].rolling(6,min_periods=2).mean()

ens['vol'] = np.where(ens['vol'].isnull(), ens['vol_5mean'], ens['vol'])
```